What are the rules for chanting names?
What are the rules for chanting names of Bhagavan/Mata (Gods/Goddesses)?
I would prefer with references from scriptures (please don’t include references from the 10 rules/offences to avoid given for the Hare Krishna Maha Mantra)

Check the book , Japa Yoga by Swami Sivananda Saraswati

In the bhagavatam it is said

apavitrah pavitro vā sarvāvasthāṁ gato api vā yaḥ smaret puṇḍarīkākṣaṁ sa bahya abhyantaraṁ śuciḥ (6.8.4-6)

Meaning May we, whether pure or impure,  in all situations and circumstances,  achieve both inner and outer purity by remembering  the divine name of the lotus-eyed all-pervading Divinity/Lord.
But while in bathroom shastras say not to speak anything so do naam jap in mind only at that time.
Source

Thanks. The link you had sent mentions that one can chant the name even if one is doing the most grievous sin.
